# Why can i not access the inside of this function - missing something basic

Tags: javascript, function, return

Currently working through codewars and I seem to be running into the same issue over and over again, I cannot return the inner functionality. The below is the current example but it happens every time I try something.

The question posed is:

Consider an array of sheep where some sheep may be missing from their place. We need a function that counts the number of sheep present in the array (true means present).

For example,

```
arrayOfSheep = [true,  true,  true,  false,
  true,  true,  true,  true ,
  true,  false, true,  false,
  true,  false, false, true ,
  true,  true,  true,  true ,
  false, false, true,  true];
```

So I have it working globally like the below:

```
let count = [];

for(let i = 0 ; i < arrayOfSheep.length ; i++) {
  if(arrayOfSheep[i] == true) {
    count ++;
  }
}
console.log(count);
```

which returns `17` in the terminal; the number of instances of `true` within `arrayOfSheep`. Great.

I know that to return the functionality i should use the `return` keyword.

This is the code which doesn't produce anything to the terminal:

```
function countSheeps(arrayOfSheep) {
  let count = [];
  for(i = 0 ; i < arrayOfSheep.length ; i ++) {
    if(arrayOfSheep[i] == true) {
     return count ++;
    }
  }
};

console.log(count);
```

it should just return the integer `17`. But instead I get the error message

> ReferenceError: count is not defined

What really obvious thing am I missing, I KNOW i am going to kick myself when someone is kind enough to point it out...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) You're not calling the function. 2) You're initializing `count` as an array, but incrementing it like a number.

Comment: 3. *"I know that to return the functionality i should use the return keyword."* True, but not where you have it. Use `return count;` at the **end** of the function. If you do `return` from within your loop, you exit the loop (and the function) before the loop completes. 4. Function *declarations* don't have `;` after them, only function expressions. [More on the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname/22173438#22173438)...

Comment: 5) The plural of sheep is sheep, not sheeps :)

Comment: Well the variables inside of an function live as long as the function self, that means when you try to console.log the count variable is already destroyed

Comment: as an aside: don't write `if(arrayOfSheep[i] == true)` you don't have to compare true to true. `if(arrayOfSheep[i])` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The variable `count` is **defined** inside the `countSheeps` function, so it's not accessible **outside** of that function. Plus, you didn't call the function in your example code.
2. You should increase the `count` instead of returning it since a for loop doesn't return anything.
3. A function can return some values. We're returning the final output of the variable `count` here so it can be displayed in the `console.log()`.

```js
const arrayOfSheep = [
  true,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  true
];

function countSheeps(arrayOfSheep) {
  let count = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arrayOfSheep.length; i++) {
    if (arrayOfSheep[i] == true) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  return count;
}

console.log(countSheeps(arrayOfSheep));
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say what you did, and why. (From the outset, rather than via an edit later.)

Answer (score 0):

Let is Block scope variable 
Variables declared with the let keyword can have Block Scope.

Variables declared inside a block {} can not be accessed from outside the block
if you want to use count from outside declare it as global

```
arrayOfSheep = [true,  true,  true,  false,
 true,  true,  true,  true ,
 true,  false, true,  false,
true,  false, false, true ,
true,  true,  true,  true ,
false, false, true,  true];
function countSheeps(arrayOfSheep) {
    let count = [];
     for(i = 0 ; i < arrayOfSheep.length ; i ++) {
       if(arrayOfSheep[i] == true) {
        return count ++;
       }
     }
   console.log(count);
   };
```